# How can I use something like \vspace{\baselineskip plus 10pt}

Tags: spacing

Is it possible to use `\baselineskip` with some extra glue inside of `\vspace`?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Text

\vspace{\baselineskip}
Works

\vspace{12pt plus 10pt minus 5pt}
Works

\vspace{\baselineskip plus 10pt minus 5pt}
Fails \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: On last line try `\vspace{\the\baselineskip plus 10pt minus 5pt}`

Comment: @YiannisLazarides This won't work if `\baselineskip` has a non zero stretch or shrink component. Usually `\baselineskip` hasn't, but other glue parameter could.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I guess is better to be conservative and use `dimexpr`, although most classes fix it in order to set `\textheight` to be a multiple of `\baseline`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides It's `\glueexpr`, anyway.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since `\vspace` wants a "glue" as its argument and `\baselineskip` *is* a glue parameter, `\vspace{\baselineskip plus 10pt minus 5pt}` is incorrect; the easiest way is to say

```
\vspace{1\baselineskip plus 10pt minus 5pt}
```

as `1\baselineskip` will make it into a simple dimension, discarding its possible `plus` and `minus` components.

Usually `\baselineskip` has zero stretching and shrinking components. If one wants to be on the safe side and add 10pt to the stretch and 5pt to the shrink components whatever they are, the "correct" way is

```
\vspace{\glueexpr\baselineskip + 0pt plus 10pt minus 5pt\relax}
```

Note: `\vspace{\dimexpr\baselineskip plus 10pt minus 5pt\relax}` works because when TeX scans for the `\dimexpr` it arrives to the `p` that cannot be part of a dimension expression and stops the scanning, having already converted `\baselineskip` to a dimension discarding the stretch and shrink components. So the final `\relax` is *not* the delimiter of `\dimexpr` and will go into the input stream (where it probably does no harm).